# Using error_log to debug a php file

Tags: php, error-log

I have a PHP file that runs ever hour on my server. I want to do some debugging by sending the value of certain variables
to my e-mail address or a log file. I tried adding the following test code, but I'm not receving e-mails or finding the log file

```
error_log("Test 123", 1, "me@mydomain.com");
error_log("Test 123", 3, "/tmp/my_errors.log");
```

I'm not sure what I need to initialize in my php.ini file or elsewhere to make this work.

Comment: I would recommend the [Monolog](https://github.com/Seldaek/monolog) package.

Answer (score 0):

You should change the second parameter accordingly. Try using 0, that would write to the default error log file.

```
error_log("Test 123", 0);
```

For message_type == 1 you need to make sure that sending e-mails work on your server, and that the 'extra_headers' parameter is set.

For message_type == 3 make sure that php can write to this file.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-log.php

Comment: message_type == 3 Also add a new line "\n" to the end of the message

Comment: Check it in php.ini, default is: error_log = /var/log/php_errors.log

Comment: No file name php_errors.log found at /var/log.
So I looked and found my php.ini file under /etc
No error log path was set (still at default - yet can't figure out what the default file name and path actuall is).
So I added the following line
     error_log = /var/tmp/php_debug.log
made sure there is write and execute priveledge on /tmp
Still not working. No file named php_debug is being created and written to.
For reference the line I have in my PHP file that runs often is
     error_log("Test123", 0);